# Azure DevOps server / TFS monitor count and list declared fields in a project collection

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a question regarding to the limits imposed on the number of objects one can declare on a TFS project collection. Not so much as to the limits themselves as to how I can check and monitor the current state.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/work-item-fields?view=azure-devops-2019) states 512 custom fields per process and 256 per WIT. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=azure-devops-2019) states 1024 while also stating a restriction on project collection level

What I'd like to clarify is the way the fields and processes add up to those totals on an TFS 2018 on-premise collection and Azure DevOps server.

- Is there a way to check the number of fields currently used
  throughout a collection?
- By "Fields defined for a collection" we are
  referring to the **unique** field reference names as they are
  declared in the WIT xmls regardless of them being used in multiple
  WITs or projects, or there is something I'm missing?
- Especially in the inherited processes in Azure DevOps the allowed fields per collection are 8192. Do they count differently (as customization is scoped to the process instead to the project) or is it simply the way it is?

Looking around I found tbl_Field in the collection database. I recognize a lot of reference names and it could do the trick but after seeing several entries that don't strike me as WIT fields (by the name they seem to relate to Kanban boards) I'm not that sure.

As for the fields in a process I guess one can scan the WIT xmls for unique referenceNames, unless someone in the community has a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could use the following Api to list all fields in a collection:

   `GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/wit/fields?api-version=5.0`
2. From my test, collection using Inheritance Process Model,  `fields` here mean all fields (not the unique field reference names) in a collection. but in collection using XML Process Model, `fields` here mean unique field reference names.
3. From the result of api, inherited processes count differently from xml processes.